# Failing to install .NET Framework 4.8 from winetricks

Tags: 18.04, windows, wine, winetricks

I want to run an .exe app to my PC but it requires .NET Framework 4.8 to be installed. I have installed Wine in the past. Now, as I have read from others, I opened the terminal and ran this command:

```
winetricks
```

After that I followed this path:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

   Some warnings???
4. [image]
5. [image]

   Set up of NET Framework:
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]

I cannot understand what went wrong. Before doing that it successfully installed **dotnet 40**.
Do you have any suggestions what went wrong and what should I do to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. I currently have this issue. Did you find any solution for that?